# Fill NA values in Pandas Dataframe using Collaborative Filtering

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, collaborative-filtering, data-cleaning

I am working on a database of Organic Compounds, and some of the cells have NA values (look at the HFUS column in the second pic):

[image]

[image]

For the purposes of my project, I would like to fill these blank spaces using collaborative filtering, instead of simple mean or median imputation. That is, for the column whose NA value will be filled, we are supposed to find the most similar row(s) comprising the other columns, and then fill in that attribute from those rows. I would like to do this recursively and fill in all the NA values.

How do I go about doing this? I found code to do a corr() with the other columns in [this link](http://tungwaiyip.info/2012/Collaborative%20Filtering.html) , but I could not get much past creating the corr values.

Here's the CSV (33kb) that can be loaded to Pandas: [features.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8e6bvqev5u0ainj/features.csv?dl=0)

Comment: Do you want the algorithm to predict these values or just how you can find these rows?

Comment: I want to predict and fill the missing NA values, ultimately using the collaborative filtering approach.

Comment: I think low-rank matrix-factorization would be a powerful approach here, but it would imply some work (dummy_features to get rid of your categorical-col; normalization; probably leaving pandas for a moment). But every approach is depending on specifics, and in your example it looks like NaNs are just within one column (which might change something)

Comment: For using collaborative filtering you can whether implement the algorithm yourself or using libraries like google sci-kit surprise. You should consider the HFUS column as the pivot and predict its value.

Comment: @aLoneStrider There are multiple columns in which values are missing, for example for heavier compounds, more than half of the features have NA values, not just HFUS. The answer would have to take this into account...I cannot drop compounds for my analysis.

Comment: @sascha, NaNs are in other columns as well, as we go to heavier compounds the rows become sparser. Should I upload the last 20 rows?

Comment: You should determine the columns which have a valid value and must be considered in the pivot table to predict missing values in other ones. Otherwise, deploying content filtering is a better approach I think.

Comment: @sascha I have linked the csv file to the question so that you can take a look at the entire dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some small and hacky demo to show some characteristics and needs of [low-rank matrix-factorization approaches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation) (written from scratch here!).

I won't give any guarantees that this is necessarily the right approach for your task, but this approach is usually quite good in the reconstruction of matrices (although your dataset seems to be very small).

Here my code is using some example-dataset and we are introducing some fake-Nans to check after if our code is doing something useful. Especially this last-step is not implemented in a nice and usable way (and i'm not going to correct that; a lot of pandas and sklearn usage).

The basic idea of the code is:

**Prepare data**

- Load [Airline dataset](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/datasets.html) (also one categorical and not many columns)
- Add some random NaNs
- Use [sklearn's](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) [MaxAbsScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MaxAbsScaler.html) for preprocessing to scale columns!

  - MaxAbsScaler used to not destroy sparsity (probably not the right approach for your case)
  - MaxAbsScaler / sklearn's preprocessing in general can't handle NaNs

    - For this step: use sklearn's (simple) [Imputer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer) to prepare for scaling
- Handle categorical column -> binary-encoding
- Use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) [Sparse data structures](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/sparse.html) to prepare the data-format for my Matrix-Factorization code

  - My MF-code (which i wrote some time ago) is based on the idea of very sparse data!
  - This is a huge hack and only pays off for very sparse data
  - But not a computational bottleneck in your problem i would suppose

**Train low-rank matrix-factorization**

- I'm using the [max-norm / γ2-norm](http://research.cs.rutgers.edu/~troyjlee/haifa.pdf) for regularization, which has very strong theoretical and empirical results in terms of matrix-reconstruction (much better with non-uniform NaNs compared to trace-norm)

  - Some scientific [overview](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~nati/Publications/SrebroShraibmanCOLT05.pdf)
- Learning is done by **Projected Stochastic Gradient Descent** following [this paper](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~brecht/papers/maxnorm.NIPS10.pdf)

  - Developed for huge and very sparse (~99% sparsity-ratio) data like Netflix-dataset and co.! Not necessarily the right tool here
  - Your dataset is so small that you could even use Semidefinite programming
    (not trivial to use without previous knowledge) which do not need tuned parameters (apart from regularization, which is a model-decision!)
  - As most online first-order methods: a lot of parameters to tune!

**Code**

```
from pydataset import data
import time
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.sparse as sp
from sklearn.preprocessing import MaxAbsScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer  # only for preprocessing
np.random.seed(1)
np.set_printoptions(precision=3, threshold=None, linewidth=140)

""" Load data """
df = data('Airline')
print(df.head())
print(df.describe())

""" Fake Nans """
mask = np.random.choice([True, False], p=[0.05, 0.95], size=df.shape)
mask[mask.all(1),-1] = 0
df_nans = df.mask(mask)

""" Normalization """
imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0)
df_nans_imputed = pd.DataFrame(imp.fit_transform(df_nans), columns=df_nans.columns) # hacky?
maxabs_scaler = MaxAbsScaler()                                                      # keep sparsity
df_nans_imputed_scaled = pd.DataFrame(maxabs_scaler.fit_transform(df_nans_imputed), columns=df_nans.columns)
df_nans_imputed_scaled = df_nans_imputed_scaled.mask(mask)                          # remove temp-imputed

print('after normalization and masking imputes')
print(df_nans_imputed_scaled.head())

""" Categoricals -> dummies """
df_nans = pd.concat([df_nans_imputed_scaled, pd.get_dummies(df_nans_imputed_scaled['airline'])], axis=1)
del df_nans['airline']

print('after dummies')
print(df_nans.head())

""" Preprocessing for MF -> bit of a hack => sparse mat just for coo-like access """
df_nans_sparse = df_nans.to_sparse()
df_nans_spcoo = df_nans_sparse.to_coo()

""" Max-norm regularized matrix-factorization """
class MaxNormMF():
    def __init__(self, coo_mat):
        self.M, self.N = coo_mat.shape
        self.NNZ = coo_mat.nnz
        self.ratings = coo_mat.data
        self.rows = coo_mat.row
        self.cols = coo_mat.col

    def calc_train_loss(self):
        n = self.NNZ
        e = 0.0
        for ind in range(n):
            i, j = self.rows[ind], self.cols[ind]
            r = self.ratings[ind]
            e += math.pow(np.dot(self.L[i, :], self.R[j, :].T) - r, 2)
        return math.pow(e / n, 0.5)

    def train(self, k=10, b=2, epochs=50, gamma=0.1, gamma_red_factor=0.9,
              show_progress=True, show_train_error=True):
        self.start_time = time.perf_counter()

        self.k = k
        self.b = b
        self.L = np.random.randn(len(self.rows), self.k) * 0.001
        self.R = np.random.randn(len(self.cols), self.k) * 0.001

        b_sqrt = math.sqrt(self.b)
        def project(v):
            v_norm = np.linalg.norm(v)
            if np.square(v_norm) >= self.b:
                return (b_sqrt * v) / v_norm
            else:
                return v

        perm_indices = np.arange(self.NNZ)

        for epoch in range(epochs):
            if show_progress:
                if epoch % 5 == 0:
                    print('epoch: ', epoch)
                    print(' secs: ', time.perf_counter() - self.start_time)
            if show_train_error:
                if (epoch != 0) and (epoch % 5 == 0):
                    e = self.calc_train_loss()
                    print(' -> ', e)

            np.random.shuffle(perm_indices)

            for ind in perm_indices:
                i, j = self.rows[ind], self.cols[ind]
                r = self.ratings[ind]

                pred = np.dot(self.L[i, :], self.R[j, :].T)

                # update rule
                grad = pred - r
                L_pre = self.L[i, :] - gamma * grad * self.R[j, :]
                R_pre = self.R[j, :] - gamma * grad * self.L[i, :]

                # projection
                self.L[i, :] = project(L_pre)
                self.R[j, :] = project(R_pre)

            # decr learning-rate
            gamma *= gamma_red_factor

        print(self.L)
        print(self.R)

    def predict(self, u, i):
        return np.dot(self.L[u, :], self.R[i, :].T)

maxnorm = MaxNormMF(df_nans_spcoo)
maxnorm.train(k=11, b=1.35, epochs=350, gamma=0.5, gamma_red_factor=0.99)

""" Look at original vals vs. imputation """
shifted_mask = mask[:, 1:]  # HACK -> shift mask because of categoricals

nan_indices = shifted_mask.nonzero()
n_nans = len(nan_indices[0])
df_nans_spcoo_dok = df_nans_spcoo.todok()  # needed for single-item-based access!
for i in range(n_nans):
    row, col = nan_indices[0][i], nan_indices[1][i]
    prediction = maxnorm.predict(row, col)
    df_nans_spcoo_dok[row, col] = prediction

    print('row,col,pred: ', row, col, prediction)

df_nans_spcoo_imputed = df_nans_spcoo_dok.tocoo()

""" Compare: incomplete re-mapping!!! Just a demo """

print('Original')
print(maxabs_scaler.transform(df.as_matrix())[:, 1:])
print('Imputed')
print(df_nans_spcoo_imputed.todense()[:, :5])
print('Mask')
print(shifted_mask.astype(int))
```

Some trimmed output:

```
Original:
[[ 0.067  0.24   0.492  0.105  0.79 ]
 [ 0.133  0.256  0.51   0.109  0.787]
 [ 0.2    0.276  0.564  0.109  0.81 ]
 [ 0.267  0.318  0.607  0.12   0.8  ]
 [ 0.333  0.353  0.599  0.194  0.874]
 [ 0.4    0.384  0.606  0.262  0.851]
 [ 0.467  0.426  0.666  0.26   0.879]
 [ 0.533  0.487  0.718  0.312  0.883]
 [ 0.6    0.556  0.833  0.379  0.944]
 [ 0.667  0.684  0.943  0.562  1.   ]
Imputed
[[ 0.067  0.288  0.492  0.105  0.79 ]
 [ 0.133  0.256  0.51   0.109  0.787]
 [ 0.2    0.359  0.564  0.109  0.81 ]
 [ 0.267  0.318  0.607  0.12   0.8  ]
 [ 0.333  0.353  0.585  0.194  0.874]
 [ 0.4    0.384  0.606  0.262  0.851]
 [ 0.467  0.479  0.666  0.26   0.879]
 [ 0.533  0.487  0.718  0.312  0.883]
 [ 0.6    0.668  0.833  0.379  0.944]
 [ 0.667  0.684  0.943  0.562  1.   ]
Mask
[[0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to transpose the matrix. To create recommend for HFUS, you need to find closet element based on other fields.

from your link

```
tf_trans = td.T
target = tf_trans[traget_col]
sim_target = tf.corrwith(target)
```

I think you also can use cosine to find similarity and iterate all col to find best one.

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine
tf_trans = td.T
target = tf_trans[traget_col]
sim = 1 - cosine(target, tf_trans[some col])
```

Comment: I have appended the csv file to the dataset. The NaNs are not just in one column. Can you take a look now?

Comment: @Avijit apply the function to all the col

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Iterative SVD from FancyImpute to solve the problem.